# Should I install a node module that builds a C library on the CI or on the target server?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, node-gyp

**Scenario**: my node application is tested and built on my CI (`npm install` and `npm test`). It is then packaged, along with the node_modules folder, and deployed to the target environment.

So far so good.

I then included a module, [node-argon2](https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2), that upon installation builds a c library using [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). The c library now is built during `npm install` on the CI (an Amazon Linux machine), the whole app is packaged and deployer to the target server (another Amazon Linux machine). The application now gives an error when I use the module *node-argon2* giving this error: `Illegal instruction`.

I assume that it's because the library compilation writes something tied to the current environment and thus, if moved to another environment, it doesn't work as expected.

If I rebuild the library on the target machine, everything works smoothly.

So here comes my brainstorming:

1. Should I install that module on the target machine on every deploy? Should I install the whole app on the target machine rather than on the CI (this doesn't seems right to me)?
2. Should I install that specific module that builds something environment-specific globally (`npm install node-argon2 -g`) and link it (`npm link node-argon2`) in the app directory?
3. Should I fix the compilation of that c library so that it will work on the target machine (no idea how to do so)?

I'd also like to know if I'm completely missing a best practice in what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It's because `node-argon2` is built with `-march=native` and meant to be compiled on the target machine, not pre-packaged. You might fork it and edit the build flags, but it's that way for maximum performance on all machines. (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about packaging your application using [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). Containerising Node with Docker is incredibly [easy](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/).

If you don't want to tackle that right now I think you should consider re-installing the npm packages on every deployment - this is the most reliable way IMO.